# Can't save a List to db.ListProperty() on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am getting an error when trying to save a list to google datastore:

```
raise BadValueError('Property %s must be a list' % self.name)
BadValueError: Property contactCountry must be a list
```

contactCountry was created as a list:

```
contactCountry = list()
```

And later appended with:

```
contactCountry.append(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('country')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)
```

For this specific example, there is only one element, but it is still a list... however I am getting that error when I try to save it. Any ideas?

Outputs of:

```
logging.info(contactCountry)
logging.info(type(contactCountry))
```

Are:

```
INFO     2013-12-02 16:38:27,349 downloadAndUpdate.py:72] [u'United States']
INFO     2013-12-02 16:38:27,349 downloadAndUpdate.py:73] <type 'list'>
```

When I have that error... I'm completely stuck... thanks!

EDIT:

Here is how I define and assign contactCountry:

```
Database = models.Database() #construct Database object
Information =  Database.get_or_insert(Identifier)
Information.contactCountry = contactCountry
```

The relevant parts of my models.py file in the same directory has this structure:

```
class Database(db.Model):
        contactCountry = db.ListProperty(str)
```

EDIT2:

I was able to get it to work -- contactCountry was originally in my datastore as a db.StringProperty() and already populated with values. I wanted to change contactCountry to a list, so I changed my models.py file to db.ListProperty(str), which is when I started seeing the error. I decided to try just clearing my datastore with

```
$ dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore [myappname]
```

and rebuilding it. The same exact code worked again for some reason after clearing my datastore and trying again.

Comment: How are you assigning `contactCountry` to the entity you are updating?

Comment: I updated my original post showing how I assign contactCountry to the entity... thanks

Comment: This looks OK, but there are now too many fragmented bits of code, which makes it hard to see exactly what is going on. I think it would be helpful if you posted the whole handler so we can be sure that contactCountry is what it is supposed to be at the point you actually put it back to the datastore.

Comment: Solved... I originally had contactCountry as a db.StringProperty(), until I found out that I may have multiple countries, so I needed to store it as a list. I changed my models.py file accordingly, and then ran into that error. However, since my database was already populated with contactCountry as a string, I tried just deleting the database and trying again with:

    $ dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore=yes [myappname]

And then ran the code again and it worked now... I don't know why, though.. thank you though for your help!

Comment: When you do a put, it puts the entire entity into the datastore. So it's possible that you did a get, which pulls the "ListProperty" as a string, since that is what it was stored as. Then when you do a put, it will try to put that string as is -- which then breaks. Clearing your datastore would prevent you from ever getting an entity with this ListProperty as a StringProperty, so the errors stop. If you do change your model, make sure you handle the case where you get an entity from the datastore with the old type.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, Patrick. Thank you for clarifying the problem!

Comment: Post you own answer on your question, so other people might see the solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work -- `contactCountry` was originally in my datastore as a `db.StringProperty()` and already populated with values. I wanted to change `contactCountry` to a list, so I changed my models.py file to `db.ListProperty(str)`, which is when I started seeing the error. I decided to try just clearing my datastore with

> $ dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore [myappname]

and rebuilding it. The same exact code worked again for some reason after clearing my datastore and trying again.